# Is it possible to set the width on an hr tag and float it to the left?

Tags: html, css

I want to control the size of an `hr` tag by setting `max-width: 250px;` but this also centered the element. How can I position the element at the left? I already tried `float:left` but the `hr` disappeared

```css
.dash{
  border: 0 none;
  border-top: 2px dashed #322f32;
  background: none;
  height:0;
   max-width: 250px;

}
```

```html
<hr class="dash" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add `margin-left:0;`

```css
.dash {
  border: 0 none;
  border-top: 2px dashed #322f32;
  background: none;
  height: 0;
  max-width: 250px;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<hr class="dash" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider wrapping the hr with a div and apply max-width to the div element rather than hr

check the snippet

```css
.dash {
  height: 0;
  max-width: 250px;
}
.dash hr {
  border: 0 none;
  border-top: 2px dashed #322f32;
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="dash">
  <hr />
</div>
```

Hope it helps